# Production ready template for insert script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I primarily work in javascript, pretty new to sql Server. I am supposed to insert two record in a table. I did my due diligence in development environment and my script works,However dba said to make it ready for production, but my dba guy is out of office for a while. So how can following data script could be tweaked/appended for production: Is there any generic template available that I can follow?

```
    use tpaApp
    go

   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AppVersion WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE key1 = 401 and key2 = 800)
                INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, delete)
                SELECT 401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 From AppVersion WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE key1 = 401 and key2 = 900)
                INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, delete)
                SELECT 401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0
```

--Rollback script:

```
       IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AppVersion WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE key1 = 401 AND key2 = 800)
    DELETE FROM AppVersion WHERE key1=401 and key2 =800
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AppVersion WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE key1 = 401 AND key2 = 900)
    DELETE FROM AppVersion WHERE key1=401 and key2 =900
```

Comment: Instead of looking for shortcuts understand what is going on. Why perform any of that when you could write a *single* INSERT statement to add missing rows? No need for a transaction either, INSERT is atomic

Comment: BTW `NOLOCK` is an alternative for `I have serious bugs`. It doesn't mean `go fast`, or `don't take locks`. It means `I want to read dirty data while taking excessive locks`. If you use `NOLOCK` the query is *not* production-ready by definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Version**

The posted queries on the other hand are seriously flawed and can lead to bad data. You can insert all rows in a single safe statement that doesn't take excessive locks :

```
INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, [delete])
SELECT 
    newrows.key1, newrows.key2, newrows.name, newrows.value,
    newrows.timestamp, newrows.changed, newrows.disabled, newrows.[delete]
FROM ( VALUES
        (401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0),
        (401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0) 
      ) newrows (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, [delete])
LEFT OUTER JOIN AppVersion 
    ON newrows.key1=AAppversion.key1 and newrows.key2=Appversion.key2
WHERE Appversion.key1 is null and #Appversion.key2 is null
```

**Explanation**

First, these queries exhibit several serious problems. The `NOLOCK` hint and the attempt to use `DELETE` instead of transactions is a very strong indication that there are blocking issues. Trying to cover them up though won't help, in fact it makes things *worse*. `NOLOCK` for example  doesn't mean `don't take locks`. It means `don't respect locks, ie read dirty data while taking excessive locks yourself`. It means that if some other transaction inserts the same data and deletes it, your query may still see them.

I suspect there are missing indexes or badly written queries that result in blocking. Perhaps long running transactions that end up locking each other? Remember that SQL Server is one of the fastest databases. It can process millions of transactions per hour over terrabytes of data *without* such tricks. These issues should be fixed, not covered up. For example, a missing index means the SELECT query may have to lock a *lot* of rows while trying to find those that match its criteria. With a proper index it would probably only have to lock 1 row.

`INSERT .. SELECT` is used to insert the results of queries, not specific values. To insert specific values you should use the `VALUES` clause. You can add multiple rows in a single statement, eg:

```
INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, delete)
VALUES 
    (401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0),
    (401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0)
```

Individual INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE statements are atomic, ie they will be rolled back automatically if they fail. They *don't* need an explicit transaction. In any case, deleting rows is *not* the same as rolling back. If there's a serious issue the `DELETE` clause may never be called, leaving ghost entries in the database.

If you want to insert only new entries, you can left join the values with the target table and insert only the new ones. If you were comparing a source and target table you coudl write :

```
INSERT into Target (ID,a,b,c)
SELECT source.ID,source.a,source.b,source.c
FROM source 
LEFT OUTER JOIN target on source.ID = target.ID
where target.ID is null
```

This will select only the source rows that have no matching target key and insert them.

You can treat values as if they were a table too, by surrounding them in parentheses and providing a table and column names, eg:

```
FROM ( VALUES
        (401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0),
        (401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0) 
) newrows (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, [delete])
```

This way you can insert only new rows with :

```
INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, [delete])
SELECT 
    newrows.key1, newrows.key2, newrows.name, newrows.value,
    newrows.timestamp, newrows.changed, newrows.disabled, newrows.[delete]
FROM ( VALUES
        (401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0),
        (401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', GETDATE(), 0, 0, 0) 
      ) newrows (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, [delete])
LEFT OUTER JOIN AppVersion 
    ON newrows.key1=AAppversion.key1 and newrows.key2=Appversion.key2
WHERE Appversion.key1 is null and #Appversion.key2 is null
```

**Reducing blocking**

As for the implied blocking problems, you should eliminate long running transactions and unnecessary queries, remove NOLOCKs and ensure all tables have the proper indexes. If `AppVersion` has Primary key that starts with the `key1` and `key2` columns, or if there is an index that starts with them, locking will be minimal.

Another consideration is to use [Snapshot isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server), especially `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` at the database level. This will allow readers to read existing data even if a writer started modifying them. The server will start making copies of old rows as writers change them, ensuring that readers can still read the data without blocking the writers.

In a way, that's what you tried (but failed) to do with the `NOLOCK` hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough template. But your organisation may have set rules and standards that differ from this.

```
    --No point slowing things down by calling GETDATE() twice
    DECLARE @dtm DATETIME = GETDATE();

    --Remove the (NOLOCK ) you need to be sure the SELECT statement returns 100% accurate results.
    --Perform inside a single Transaction to ensure nothing changes between IF statement and INSERT statement
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AppVersion WHERE key1 = 401 and key2 = 800)
                        INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, delete)
                        SELECT 401, 800, 'AndroidVersion', '1.0.1',@dtm, 0, 0, 0

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 From AppVersion WHERE key1 = 401 and key2 = 900)
                        INSERT INTO AppVersion (key1, key2, name, value, timestamp, changed, disabled, delete)
                        SELECT 401, 900, 'IosVersion', '1.0.1', @dtm, 0, 0, 0
        COMMIT 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      -- Determine if an error occurred.  
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
         ROLLBACK 

        --PUT YOUR ERROR HANDLING HERE  i.e Log Error

    END CATCH;
```

Comment: That's *not* a good query. It executes 2 queries to insert one record. You can insert multiple rows with one INSERT statement. You can use INSERT with a `FROM` clause that eliminates existing rows. A single INSERT is atomic so it doesn't ned an explicit transaction either

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos the OP is primarily asking for a Template, optimisation isn't the priority yet.

Comment: This isn't optimization, it's writing an adequate query. Templating a bad query doesn't make it any better. And there is no `BEGIN TRAN` either. The OP is trying to *DELETE* rows in case of an unspecified error.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks for spotting the error BEGIN TRAN added.